# Image manipulation with intrinsic variables in DigitalMicrograph

Tags: dm-script

As we know that intrinsic variables in DigitalMicrograph, though sort of hard to understand, are very useful, especially in image manipulation, which is much faster than the conventional for-loop. I wonder whether these variables are able to do the following tasks:

(1) Filter an image with a given range of value. For example, survey an image pixel-by-pixel and then set the pixel to 0 if its value falls between 5-10.

(2) Project a 3D datacube to a 2D image. For example, project all the energy channels to the 2D plane in the real space to get the average image (for EDS or EELS spectrum-image). This is actually similar to the function “Projection Z” available in the DM.

In the case of project 2D to 1D lineprofile, this can be achieved via:

```
image Projection := RealImage ("Integrated lineprofile", 4, sizeX, 1)
Projection [icol, 0] += Img_source
```

Will it be possible also for 3D?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no real mystery for these intrinsic variables. I'll try to give you a run-down

#### Precursor on images

When you write a script like:

```
image img
img = 10
```

what it really does in the 2nd line behind the curtain is:

```
for (i=0; i<nPixels; i++)
   img[i] = 10
```

It iterates over all pixels of the image-array (which is a *1-dimensional* list of `nPixel` values in memory, even if the image is 2D or 3D) and sets *each* of them to 10.

Accordingly, if instead of `10` you would use a different image like:

```
image img1, img2
img1 = img2
```

it becomes

```
for (i=0; i<nPixels; i++)
   img1[i] = img2[i]
```

Each array value of `img1` gets the according value of the array of `img2`.
Therefore, the two images must be of same size, or you will get an error. In fact, although the actual values are a 1D-list of values, the interpreter will check that the number of dimensions and sizes of dimensions are also the same. You can not set a 100x1 image equal to a 10x10 image in script code like this.

#### Primer on intrinsic variables

These are nothing else than place-holders for the coordinate-position of a pixel. Take `icol` for example. When evaluated, it will be replaced by the X coordinate of the pixel currently worked on. For example the script:

```
image img
img = icol
```

really becomes

```
for (i=0; i<nPixels; i++)
   img[i] = xCoordinate_of_pixel_i
```

So far, we have used *icol* only on the right-hand-side of the equation, and our "internal" for-loop goes over all `nPixels` of the image on the left-hand-side.
But that is not a condition. One can use *icol* also on the left-hand-side as in your own example, but how does it work then?

In order to work, there must be an unambiguous meaning of *icol*. It must be clear which pixel's "x" coordinate is meant, and how many pixels there are. Or, in other terms: *Something* in the whole equation must be a fixed-size-known-image. (And of course all fixed-sized-known-images must be of same size, like in the simple `img1 = img2`situation.)

Therefore one can't write something like:

```
img[icol,0] = 10
```

but one can write something like:

```
img1[icol,0] = img2 * icol
```

How does it 'translate'? `img2` is of known size, so in the whole *expression* (- just another word for the equation, because it is not really an equation in the mathematical sense. - ) the *icol* refers to that image and size. The real executed code then becomes:

```
for (i=0; i<nPixels_of_img2; i++)
   img1[xCoordinate_of_pixel_i_of_img2,0] = img2[i] * xCoordinate_of_pixel_i_of_img2
```

In the above, indexing a single value `[i]`  means just taking the i-th value of the data in memory (which is a 1D list), but indexing with two `[i,j]` really is addressing the pixels at (x/y)=(i/j). The pair is internally converted into the "real" position of the 1D-list, simply by `i + j * image_width`.

But now look at the "translated" code again: What is required for it to not fail?
Well, for once: `img1[xCoordinate_of_pixel_i_of_img2,0]` must exist. 
 `img1` must have a width at least as big as `img2`.

But even so, if you look careful at the for-loop, you will notice that the values of img1 will be rewritten multiple times! The first row of img2 will be set to img1, but then the loop continues and the first value of the second row of img2 is also written to `img1[xCoordinate_of_pixel_i_of_img2,0]`! 
(Because `xCoordinate_of_pixel_i_of_img2` becomes 0 again in the second row of img2.)

And this is *exactly* the reason why the "projection" code in your example works, because

```
Dst [icol, 0] += Src
```

really means

```
for (i=0; i<nPixels_of_Src; i++)
   Dst[ xCoordinate_of_Src_of_pixel_i, 0 ] += src[i]
```

i.e. you are adding up row after row.

## The actual question answers

### ad 1)

> No, intrinsic variables deal with the *position* in an image, not its intensity values. But thresholding by value is even simpler in scripting. You just need a ternary operator (or the 'tert()' command, which is the same.)
>
> Simply use:
>
> `img = ( (img < 5) || (img > 10) ? img : 0 )`
>
> or equivalently:
>
> `img = tert( (img < 5) || (img > 10) , img , 0 )`
>
> The operation is again performed pixel-by-pixel and the check is thus performed for each pixel's value - replacing the pixel by 0 if the condition isn't met, and keeping the value otherwise.

### ad 2)

> Yes, it directly extends from your example. You just have:
>
> ```
> image Projection := RealImage ("Integrated planes", 4, sizeX, sizeY)
> Projection [icol, irow, 0] += Img_source
> ```

#### Note 1

However, it does not extend to 4D and 5D. The reason is, that while `img[x]`, `img[x,y]` and `img[x,y,z]` are defined as representing a value in 1D, 2D, and 3D, the syntax with 4-parameters `img[t,l,b,r]` is already defined for specifying a rect-area in a 2D image.

#### Note 2

Using intrinsic variables is a lot (a real lot!) faster than doing a scripted for-loop. However, it is not the fasted you can go. The reason is, that such expression will only be computed on a single thread. Scripting, however, features commends which internally are multi-threaded. Thus, it is actually faster to have a scripted loop over one coordinate and sum up 2D images extracted with the `slice2` command.

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/q/64103457/1302888